# SSIS SQL task to compare to query values

Tags: sql, ssis

SSIS novice needs some help.  Not sure if this is possible.

I have a txt file that I am importing into SQL using SSIS.
Before I import the file, I do a row count with Powershell and update that value into Database1, Table1, Recordcount
So DB1 has:

```
DB1
FileID  RecordCount
1       1500
```

I can query the count from the table using :

```
USE Database1
SELECT RecordCount FROM Table1 WHERE (FileID = 1)
//This returns 1500
```

Next, in SSIS, I import the txt file with a Data Flow task that inserts the data into another database (DB2).  The data is then scrubbed, etc.

The FileID field from DB1 matches FileIDRef on DB2

So DB2 has:

```
DB2
Ref Name    Address  Zip    FileIDRef
1   Jim     11 Lane  33221  1
2   Bill    22 St    77665  1
>  ......    .. ..... 
1500 Jane   44 Rte   23232  1
//etc
```

I can then run a SQL query to count the rows by FileIDRef:

```
USE Database2
SELECT COUNT(FileIDRef) AS Expr1 FROM Table1 WHERE (FileIDRef = 1)
```

Now here is the question.
In the very last step of the SSIS, I need to compare FileID against FileIDREF
as sometimes the data is corrupt and not all the rows import

If the values of the 2 queries are not equal, branch to a SendMail block to send a warning.
If they match, then exit successfully

Can I do this with one SQL statement?
Or do I have to set up something in SSIS?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to store both counts in variables. Then, you assign the count value to each variable in each `Execute SQL Task`. Finally, you use constraints to check if the variable values are identical and direct flow to the appropriate branch based on the comparison result.

Comment: I'll try that.  As an SSIS newbie, trying to figure out how to capture the count to variable is not intuitive.  I will google how to do that.  Thanks!